# Will public key change on renewing a certificate?

Tags: ssl-certificate

HI,
When i renew an SSL certificate will the public key change or be the same as the expired certificate?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you re-use the same certificate request, the key will not change. If you generate a new request, that'll typically (by default) generate a new key; re-using is sometimes useful e.g., to add another alternate domain name.

If your certificate authority is not requiring a certificate request, then they must be re-using the old one.

Comment: HI,
We are running a webservice that has ssl. It was running without any probs. After the expiry date we renewed the certiicate with a new CSR. Since then the webservice is not working. It shows up some errors like "Could not establish secure channel SSL/TLS"

Comment: Can we use the old CSR to renew a certificate or is it necessary to have a new CSR for certificate.

Comment: Unless the CA objects, you can use the old one. I'm not sure *why* you'd want to, but you can.

Comment: Sorry, Actually I do not hane mush knowledge about certificates and SSL. But we are facing this sort of problem. I heard that we have to use a new CSR for renewing a certificate also. So will it cause any problem when the client tries o connect to our webservice

Comment: As long as you properly install the new key and certificate, your clients should not care. Unless you have some weird clients.

Comment: hi after renewal of ssl our android app has stopped working (ssl pinning), but our data center team (who renewd the ssl) saying that its not possbile to renew the SSL with same public key instead of new one, is this true? how to renew it with same public key please help , our ssls are from rapid ssl, thanks in advance

Comment: @ɹɐqʞɐzoɹǝɟ it's not true in general (and otherwise public key pinning wouldn't exist), but I suppose it's possible their systems don't allow it,  don't make it easy, or they just don't know how to. Or if they've already deleted the previous key.

Comment: @derobert You said the SSL certificate doesn't change right?
So, I go to godaddy and just renew my SSL subscription with old CSR, I don't need to change the SSL keys like public certificate etc. on my servers? Will nothing need to be changed?
Wouldn't newly generated SSL have another serial number and expiry than the older one?

Comment: @RanvijayJamwal the certificate (not the key) will change. You'll need to install the new certificate on your server. Sometimes those are put together in one file—in which case (with PEM format), the private key block will stay the same, but the certificate block will change.

Comment: FYI, If you re-use the same private key, the key will not change.

Comment: This answer is inaccurate. It is not about re-using the same CSR but actually re-using the same private key. You can always generate a new CSR with even different details such as adding extra Subject Alternative Names but as long as you use the same private key to sign the new CSR, the public key will be the same.

Comment: @Lukman It's focused on the OP's specific situation, but indeed that's right in general. I will edit to clarify.

Answer (score 3):

The certificate has nothing to do with the keys.  Essentially the certificate is just a signature of your public key.  You continue to reuse the same key (unless your old public key has an expiry date that's passed).

Comment: HI,
We are running a webservice that has ssl. It was running without any probs. After the expiry date we renewed the certiicate with a new CSR. Since then the webservice is not working. It shows up some errors like "Could not establish secure channel SSL/TLS"

Comment: You probably didn't install the new private key. Is this really a programming question?

Comment: No, this has nothing to do with programming.